# Error:unable to upgrade connection:Authorization error (user=kube apiserver, verb=create, resource=nodes, sub resource=proxy)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have set up my cluster with my app but now I'm facing issue in my gke cluster

Error:unable to upgrade connection:Authorization error (user=kube apiserver, verb=create, resource=nodes, sub resource=proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error looks like Authorization issue

The failure is caused by the kube-apiserver attempting to access an unrelated kubelet. This suggests that your core system's RBAC rules may be corrupt; if your installer or K8s distro doesn't have a way to validate or repair them (most don't), you can create a new cluster and compare the results to that.

Refer to this official  [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/kubelet-authn-authz/#kubelet-authentication) for more information about Authorization

Refer to this [community forum](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Google-Kubernetes-Engine-GKE/Unable-to-enter-a-pod-in-the-gke-cluster/m-p/490519)  to resolve your error

Refer to this [Gitlink](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/4645)  more information about  Authorization errors

Comment: chandini Thank you helpful